# i want to convert varchar datatype into date datatype for 'date' column in attendance_date table

Tags: mysql, date

i have a table name as attendance_date. in this table i have column as dates.and this column has a values like '29-01-2016' which have varchar datatype. now i want to reverse my date column from '29-01-2016' to '2016-01-29' format.but this newly formtted result would be in DATE datatype. please suggest me the solution for this question.

Comment: There seem to be many similar questions to this, but they all have some twist like the `DATE` only, or an occasional missing year, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('29-01-2016', '%d-%m-%Y');
+---------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('29-01-2016', '%d-%m-%Y') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2016-01-29                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It uses the [date and time formatting strings shown here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).